# Share ViewModel for two Views

Tags: c#, mvvm

I want to share one ViewModel for two Views. In App.xaml.cs I've created

```
public static MyViewMode ViewModel { get; set; }
```

First View:

```
App.ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```

Second View:

```
this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```

Is it good way, when I want to share ViewModel?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to be more clear in your question.  Are you looking to share the same instance of a view model across multiple views?  If so, why not just make the view model object a singleton object?  I would be curious as to why you want two views sharing the same instance of a view model though.

Comment: Yes, I want to share one ViewModel for 2 Views. Why? I create app for windows phone. And two pages are something like wizard(page flow). And Pages are not big, so I can't give all controls on one page, therefore I use two pages(views) but one viewmodel.

Comment: I understand.  There are other ways to do it, but the method you have will be fine, or a singleton approach will work as well.  Good luck.